# Problem with appending a graph object to lists for networkx in Python

Tags: python, list, loops, networkx

I am trying to remove nodes at random from graphs using the networkx package. The first block describes the graph construction and the second block gives me the node lists that I have to remove from my graph H (20%, 50% and 70% removals). **I want 3 versions of the base graph H in the end**, in a list or any data structure. The code in block 3 gives me objects of type *"None"*. The last block shows that it works for a single case.

I am guessing that the problem is in the **append** function, which somehow returns objects of type *"None"*. I also feel that the base graph H might be getting altered after every iteration. Is there any way around this? Any help would be appreciated :)

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
import random

# node removals from Graphs at random

# network construction
H = nx.Graph()
H.add_nodes_from([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
H.add_edges_from([[1,2],[2,4],[5,6],[7,10],[1,5],[3,6]])
nx.info(H)
nodes_list = list(H.nodes)

# list of nodes to be removed
perc = [.20,.50,.70] # percentage of nodes to be removed
random_sample_list = [] 
for p in perc:
    interior_list = []
    random.seed(2) # for replicability
    sample = round(p*10)
    random_sample = random.sample(nodes_list, sample)
    interior_list.append(random_sample)
    random_sample_list.append(random_sample)

# applying the list of nodes to be removed to create a list of graphs - not working
graph_list = []
for i in range(len(random_sample_list)):
    H1 = H.copy()
    graph_list.append(H1.remove_nodes_from(random_sample_list[i]))

# list access - works
H.remove_nodes_from(random_sample_list[1])
nx.info(H)
```

Final output should look like:
[Graph with 20% removed nodes, Graph with 50% removed nodes, Graph with 7% removed nodes] - eg. list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function [`remove_nodes_from`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.Graph.remove_nodes_from.html) does not return the modified graph, but returns `None`. Consequently, you only need to create the graph with the desired percentage of your nodes and append it to the list:

```
graph_list = []
for i in range(len(random_sample_list)):
    H1 = H.copy()
    H1.remove_nodes_from(random_sample_list[i])
    graph_list.append(H1)
```

Comment: Ahh! Now I see it! Thanks a lot for the prompt answer :D you're a lifesaver

Comment: You're welcome. Accepting the answer and/or upvote would be perfect ;)